# Exponential Sums

Tags: combinatorics, summation, generating-functions

This is my first time on the Mathematics Stack Exchange. I am currently studying for my IIT entrance exam, and while studying and browsing the web, I came across an interesting problem.

Let $a,b,c,d \ge 0$. Find a closed form for the expression: $$\sum_{a+b+c+d = n} 2^{a+2b+3c+4d}$$ in terms of $n$.

At the bottom, it said that a possible hint might be that I should use generating functions. I've been working for the past couple of hours and can't seem to figure out what the generating function of this expression would be.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you,
Rohit

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: If you multiply out $$\dfrac{1}{1-2x} \cdot \dfrac{1}{1-2^2x} = \left(\sum_{a = 0}^{\infty}2^ax^a\right) \cdot \left(\sum_{b = 0}^{\infty}2^{2b}x^b\right),$$ the $x^n$ coefficient is the sum of $2^a \cdot 2^{2b} = 2^{a+2b}$ over all integers $a,b \ge 0$ such that $a+b = n$.

Can you extend this idea to your problem?

Comment: So then, would I just have $\frac{1}{1-2x} \cdot \frac{1}{1-4x} \cdot \frac{1}{1-8x} \cdot \frac{1}{1-16x}$. The $x_n$ coefficient is exactly the sum we want to calculate. Then, I could do a partial-fraction decomposition to split this multiplication into the sum of 4 fractions and figure out the $x_n$ term that way.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the way to solve this. Good luck!

Comment: Does this solution allow for $a,b,c,d$ to not be integers? In the problem, it doesn't say anywhere that $a,b,c,d$ MUST be integers. If they don't need to be, would the answer just be infinity since there would be infinitely many combinations of $a,b,c,d$ that would work?

Comment: Wouldn't this require $x < 16$ to ensure convergence?

Comment: With generating functions, x is just a placeholder. But yes, we would need $-\frac{1}{16} < x < \frac{1}{16}$ to ensure convergence.

Comment: I implicitly assumed that $a,b,c,d$ must be non-negative integers, which would make sense for a combinatorics problem If $a,b,c,d$ could be any non-negative numbers, then there would be an uncountably infinite set of solutions, and the sum wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @delhimaths Thanks. It would appear I know significantly less about this than *you* do, so now I'm interested to see the final result. :)

Comment: So I... think I have a solution. Is it OK for me to post it? Or should I wait for OP to post theirs? I learned something today! :)